# How to download videos after they have been uploaded with web2py

Tags: video, web2py, web2py-modules

I am using web2py for my college project.

I have managed to upload a video into my database (by uploading it into 'uploads files').

But the problem is I don't know how to access that uploaded video afterwards.

Can someone explain me how can I access a video after it has been uploaded?

The intention is that user can see their videos and download them.

```
db.define_table('product',Field('TITLE',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('OWNER_ID','reference auth_user',readable=False,),
            Field('Video','upload'),
            Field('DESCRIPTION','text'),
            Field('times','datetime'),
            Field('RATE')
            )
```

Comment: Please include the code for the video upload part of your project. That will be crucial in helping us explain how to solve the problem.

Comment: Under `Field('Vide0', 'upload'),`, is that `0` supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0):

The upload field stores the name of the file, so to get the path to a file, you can do:

```
import os
row = db(db.product.id == some_id).select().first()
filepath = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads', row.Video)
```

However, web2py includes a built-in method, [`response.download`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#response) that will automatically retrieve and stream a file that has been uploaded via an upload field. The scaffolding application includes the following function in the default.py controller:

```
def download():
    """
    allows downloading of uploaded files
    http://..../[app]/default/download/[filename]
    """
    return response.download(request, db)
```

To generate a link to download via the above action, you would use the `URL` helper as follows:

```
URL('default', 'download', args=row.Video)
```

where `row` is a row from the `db.product` table. The `response.download` method will read the filename from `request.args[0]` (i.e., the first URL arg). The filename includes the db table and field name, so `response.download` uses that information to identify the upload field definition, which includes the upload file path. It then streams the file.

Comment: Thanks for your information . Can you please tell me in which filed i have to import 'os'

Comment: Import `os` in the file where you use it.

Comment: Thanks again :) . But it is showing some error like "row" and "some_id" was undeclared.

Comment: `some_id` is just a placeholder in this sample code -- you must provide the ID of a product record somehow. Regarding the `URL()` helper, again, you are responsible for creating the `row` object referenced in `args=row.Video`. These items are beyond the scope of your question, and there is no way to know exactly how they should be defined without more context.